# How to add 2 objects to php code

Tags: php, object

I have 6 product pages with id from 1 to 6. In the shopping cart page I have this code:

```
<?php if($objcartRS["catid"]==1 ){ echo "xxx"; ?>   <?php } else { echo "yyy"; }?>
```

My problem is how can I add another page for ex the one with id 2 so it will be just 1 and 2 that will take the name `xxx` and the rest of the pages `yyy`?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: if($objcartRS["catid"]==1 || if($objcartRS["catid"]==2) ?

Comment: also as a variant you can use switch statement

Comment: `<?php if($objcartRS["catid"]==1  ||  $objcartRS["catid"] == 2){ echo "xxx"; ?>   <?php } else { echo "yyy"; }?>`

Comment: Thank you both! I didn't expect an answer that fast. That work great. :)

Comment: `@vld` I added as an answer. Please mark it as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said based on that you have to do very simple change in you condition that is add another condition in `if` with `||`operator like below:-

```
<?php if($objcartRS["catid"]==1 || $objcartRS["catid"] == 2){ echo "xxx"; ?> <?php } else { echo "yyy"; }?>
```

Note:- Please note that `$objcartRS["catid"]` value must be integer type otherwise your condition will false. In that case you need to typecast your value to integer.